# Buttons look different on storyboard to view

Tags: ios, swift

Why is my the elements of my storyboard (buttons) showing up differently in the simulator to the device? I've got auto-layout on, and I've disabled size-classes but surely this shouldn't matter?

How it looks in the storyboard: http://s11.postimg.org/h1xbn5f9v/Screen_Shot_2016_02_09_at_18_57_54.png

It looks fine on the iPhone 5 (it matches the storyboard), although on the iPhone 6 and other devices it's different.

How it looks on the iPhone 6:
http://s17.postimg.org/tfdaagt3y/Screen_Shot_2016_02_09_at_18_58_39.jpg

I'm using a view to hold together the buttons and centered it horizontally.

Any ideas? I'm baffled. It seems I'll have to programmatically place it if this is the case...

Comment: what are the constraints you set up for the button with auto layout?

Comment: Here: http://s29.postimg.org/fql5t7s7r/Screen_Shot_2016_02_09_at_19_41_23.png

Comment: The only thing i see different between the storyboard and the iPhone 6 picture is in the story board it is closer to the bottom of the screen. Is this your problem?  If so I don't see you having a constraint for distance from bottom of the screen

Comment: I've added that and now it's perfect on the iPhone 5, but on the iPhone 6 it's completey different: http://s17.postimg.org/n73y45gf3/Screen_Shot_2016_02_09_at_19_52_15.png

Comment: Where are your constraints describing how to position your `UIViews`? You need to tell Autolayout the `x` and `y` coordinates of the views or specify them relative to their superview (for instance `centre horizontally` or `centre vertically`). The constraints you have shown so far are only size (`width` and `height`) constraints. Add this info to your question NOT the comments.

Answer (score 0):

From the images you've shared thus far, I don't see any constraints other than the height/width. You need to select the buttons of interest and then hold Control and drag to the bottom of the container, click "Vertical Spacing to Bottom Layout Guide" and then on the right panel, set Vertical Space Constant to adjust (incase you find yourself having to temporarily place the button in the container to get the "Vertical Spacing to Bottom Layout Guide" option when Control + Dragging). Looks like you'll need a negative number for the Vertical Spacing constant to achieve the buttons being slightly out the bottom of the container. Then "Update Frames for Selected View" by pressing Control + Option + =

You can also try clicking the little triangle [icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EosXW.png) and clicking "Add Missing Constraints." This will add missing constraints needed to keep your icons where they are in the Storyboard, but sometimes I've found that using this automatic feature doesn't achieve my exact intent.